A property of an irreducible root system
Let $\Phi$ be an irreducible root system. Let $\alpha_k$ be a simple root. I recently observed that the number of positive roots which are bigger than $\alpha_k$ and of height $m$ is same as the number of positive roots bigger than $\alpha_k$ and of height $h-m-1$, where $h$ is the coxeter number of $\Phi$ which is just one more than the height of the highest root. Is there an uniform proof of this statement ?

Quick comment, not a full answer: if $\omega_k$ is a minuscule weight, then the subposet of the root poset above the simple root $\alpha_k$ is the corresponding minuscule poset, and it is well-known that minuscule posets are self-dual (in a sense the duality can be realized by multiplication by the longest element of the Weyl group), explaining your observation in this case. I have not thought about principal order filters generated by non-minuscule simple roots. That seems interesting...

When $m=0$ there are no roots bigger than $\alpha_k$ of height $0$, while the highest root is bigger than $\alpha_k$ of height $h-1$.

It should be $h-m-1$ for $1 \leq m \leq h-2$. @Sam Hopkins, isn't that $-w_0$ takes $\alpha_k$ to $\alpha_{n+1-k}$ in the $A_n$ root system ? What do you mean duality here ?

@jack I’m not talking about the Dynkin diagram symmetry. The relevant action of $w_0$ here is not on the roots, it’s on the weights of the minuscule representation (whose poset is the distributive lattice of order ideals of the minuscule poset). By duality I mean order duality: the minuscule poset is isomorphic to its dual (opposite order, i.e., Hasse diagram turned upside down). See e.g. Thomas and Yong https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608276. I could also write more as an answer if you want.

@jack Probably you mean $h-m$ instead of $h-m-1$ or else this fails for $\alpha_2$ in type $A$. With that change it's true in any type whenever $\alpha_k$ has coefficient $1$ in the highest root, as Sam describes. It's not true generally, for instance if $\alpha_k$ is the central node in $D_4$ and $m=2$, then there are 3 roots over $\alpha_k$ of height $2$ but only 1 of height $6-2$.

@GrantB. Nice counterexample! So I wonder whether this property characterizes the simple roots corresponding to minuscule weights.
